# Blazor update query param or segment dynamically

Tags: blazor, blazor-server-side, .net-core-3.0

Is it possible to update the URL dynamically with Blazor?

I have a page where a user can do a search by entering specific terms in an input field. What I want is when the user hits the "search" button, that the URL is updated with the search criteria. But **without** doing a page refresh.

So that it looks something like this:

`localhost:1234/data?filter=search+criteria+here`

Or using segments would be fine as well, if that is possible:

`localhost:1234/data#filter=search+criteria+here`

So basically much like how Google works, but without a complete page refresh.

Is it possible to do this with Blazor?

Comment: Is that help : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/routing?view=aspnetcore-3.0 ?

Comment: @aguafrommars Thanks, but I don't think that is what I need. It doesn't tell if there is a way to dynamically update the URL without doing an actual GET request.

Comment: The routing system doesn't do a GET request, it just change the browser url, as Angular or other SPA frameworks do.

Comment: @aguafrommars Ah thanks, I wasn't aware of that. I'll have another look into it.